# MySQL server in a docker container doesn't work after commiting the container

Tags: mysql, docker

I created docker-compose.yml file, which creates MySQL image and sets the password of MySQL root user to "hello".

```
# docker-compose.yml

version: '3.1'

services:

  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.6.40
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    restart: always
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=hello
      - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=hello
      - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=hello
```

Then I run:

```
sudo docker-compose up # (1)
```

... from the directory with this file.

The first problem is that the newly created container starts running in the foreground but not in bash and I can't put it in the background without exiting it, which I can do by Ctrl+C, or somehow enter bash, getting out from this process.

But when I open a new terminal window and run:

```
sudo docker exec -it bdebee1b8090 /bin/bash # (2)
```

..., where bdebee1b8090 is the id of the running container, I enter bash, where I can enter MySQL shell as root user, entering password "hello":

```
mysql -u root -p # (3)
```

[image]

Then I exit MySQL shell and bash shell in the container without stopping the container.

And then I commit changes to the container:

```
sudo docker commit bdebee1b8090 hello_mysql # (4)
```

..., creating a image. And then, when I run the image:

```
sudo docker run -it --rm hello_mysql /bin/bash # (5)
```

... and try to start MySQL shell again as root user, entering password "hello", I get an error like

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

[image]

And even after I restart the MySQL server:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql restart # (6)
```

..., I get the same error.

All of the above commands were run on ubuntu.

Why is this happening?

**Edit:**

When I try to make those steps on MacOS High Sierra, I get stuck on the step (3), because when I try to enter the password "hello", it doesn't get accepted. This error is shown on the screen:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

[image: b]

And when I try to restart MySQL server in the container

```
/etc/init.d/mysql restart
```

..., the container restarts in the background

[image]

..., but when I run it again and try to repeat steps (2) and (3) it gives the same error, and when I restart the MySQL server again, the container restarts in the background again...

**Edit2:**

After I removed lines:

```
  - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=hello
  - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=hello      -
```

...it started to work on Mac, but still after I commit the container, and try to enter the MySQL shell, it gives and error like:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

.... again.

Comment: Did you read the manual for MySQL container? `- MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=hello` - what do you mean by this? and that `- MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=hello` ?

Comment: Ok, I was being stupid, when I wrote this: 


`MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=hello MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=hello`

Answer (score 1):

According to official documentation for MySQL docker images

https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-server/

> The boolean variables including MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD,
>   MYSQL_ONETIME_PASSWORD, MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD, and
>   MYSQL_LOG_CONSOLE are made true by setting them with any strings of
>   non-zero lengths. Therefore, setting them to, for example, “0”,
>   “false”, or “no” does not make them false, but actually makes them
>   true. This is a known issue of the MySQL Server containers.

Which means your config:

```
  - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=hello
  - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=hello
```

equal to:

```
  - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD = true
  - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD = true
```

Which bring us to the point:

> MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: When this variable is true (which is its
>   default state, unless MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD is set or
>   MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD is set to true), a random password for the
>   server's root user is generated when the Docker container is started.
>   The password is printed to stdout of the container and can be found by
>   looking at the container’s log.

So either check your container log file to find random password generated
or just remove config parameter `MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD` from your file.

Comment: After commiting the container even without those two silly options `MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=hello MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=hello`, mysql still doesn't work.

Comment: @ibodi post your full docker compose file please

Comment: this docker file in the post is the one. Just delete lines `MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=hello MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=hello`

Answer (score 1):

Docker images are generally designed to run a single process or server, in the foreground, until they exit.  The standard `mysql` image works this way: if you `docker run mysql` without `-d` you will see all of the server logs printed to stdout, and there’s not an immediate option to get a shell.  You should think of interactive shells in containers as a debugging convenience, and not the usual way Docker containers run.

When you `docker run --rm -it /bin/bash`, it runs the interactive shell *instead* of the database server, and that’s why you get the “can’t connect to server” error.  As a general rule you should assume things like init.d scripts just don’t work in Docker; depending on the specific setup they might, but again, they’re not the usual way Docker containers run.

You can install a `mysql` client binary on your host or elsewhere and use that to interact with the server running in the container.  You don’t need an interactive shell in a container to do any of what you’re describing here.

Comment: But I want to create a db in a container, commit it and then, after running the created image, have access to the same db.

Answer (score 1):

Bit late here:
i also faced this issue.
i took an ubuntu image and ran apt-get install mysql-server it worked fine in current instance but after commiting it into image it didnt work and i was unable to up the service as well.

so in ubuntu i made it to apt-get install mariadb-server.After commiting it in image in new container i ran service mysql start; mysql 
It worked fine !